# Code 'nicely' an output from an array (foreach with use of substr)

Tags: php, arrays, string, export

i would like to write 'nicely' when i code the use of an array content to make a string.

```
$array=['21260','777','32'];


foreach($array as $value)
  $tmp=$tmp.$value."','";

$FINALE_STRING="('".substr($tmp,0,strlen($tmp)-2)).")";
// the FINALE_STRING SHOULD BE THAT:   $FINALE_STRING="('21260','777','32')"
```

Thx for improving me.

Comment: what do you mean by **write 'nicely' when i code**

Comment: Your code works, you forgot to define `tmp` outside of the for loop, plus you hava an extra closing paranthesis so it's failing.

Comment: Actually; `tmp` is still in scope. He'll get an undefined variable issue but it won't fail because of that.

Comment: use rtrim($tmp,",'")

Comment: @WillParky93 Correct you are!

Answer (score 3):

Use implode to join your array values to a string:

```
$array=['21260','777','32'];
$tmp=implode("','",$array);
$FINALE_STRING="('".$tmp."')";
```

demo:https://ideone.com/EB6lM5

Comment: Thx, it was the 'long' command with a substr which i didnt find correct/nice.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works apart from one minor issue; you have an extra `)` in your `substr` call.

```
$array=['21260','777','32'];
$tmp = ""; //removes the undefined variable error you will get
foreach($array as $value)
  $tmp=$tmp.$value."','";

//old line:
// $FINALE_STRING="('".substr($tmp,0,strlen($tmp)-2)).")";
$FINALE_STRING="('".substr($tmp,0,strlen($tmp)-2).")";
```

Outputs: `('21260','777','32')`

[3v4l link](https://3v4l.org/qHWBr)

Comment: Best answer - uses Op's code. I'd still comment on the `tmp` thing.

Comment: Good idea, I've added it in. Thanks @kabanus

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php).

```
<?php
$array = ['21260','777','32'];
$final_string = "('".implode("','", $array)."')";
```